# he had gone eighty-four days now without taking a fish

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis

I'm a non English language user, but I saw this sentence in a book:

> He had gone eighty-four days now without taking a fish.

If i was the writer of that sentence, I think I would use something like:

> He didn't take a fish during eighty-four days.

So what's my problem? Why does the second sentence seem more logical for me? I would never trust and use that first sentence whatever it true.

I never have been in a country where people speak English.

So should I speak like the first sentence? How do I understand that way it is written?

Comment: Hello, the first sentence is correct.

Comment: what about second one? what you think if use it when we talk, you could think that my english is bad?

Comment: The second sentence would be okay if it was modified to "He didn't eat fish for eighty-four days running."

Comment: running? who is running fish? i never use that too. i could you he didnt eat fish during eighty-four days, is that correct?

Comment: The second sentence is perfectly adequate, and would communicate what you wanted. It would be better if it was *"he hadn't taken a fish for eight-four days"*. That is, the past perfect is somewhat better than the past in Hemingway's context, and *during* isn't usually used for time intervals like *ten days* today (although [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=during+ten+days%2C+for+ten+days&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cduring%20ten%20days%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20ten%20days%3B%2Cc0) seems to say it was in the 19th century).

Comment: Thank you @PeterShor, yes I m reading Hemingway's book, what you think is it good to read Hemingways book for learning english? And thank you for how to use "during" i didnt know that so how can i learn these usually usings with any book or  any reference?

Comment: @Michael: Since *during* was used like this in the 19th century, it's a natural usage, and also perfectly comprehensible; it just happens to not be used this way today. I don't know how you could figure it out.

Comment: But reading any good author that entertains you is a good way to learn English vocabulary. Any English book at all will work; just pick one you want to read. And then read it. You can figure stuff out if you go slow. And after a while you go faster. Of course, this doesn't tell you how to talk.

Comment: @MichaelRiva _Running_ doesn't have anything to do with the fish in Andy’s sentence. It modifies the 84 days; it is an adjective here that means ‘in a row’, so _84 days running_ means ‘84 consecutive days’ or ‘84 days in a row’.

Comment: ohh I see now, thank you guys. and @JanusBahsJacquet i never know running means consecutive, thank you for that too.

Comment: No one is wondering about 'taking a fish'?

Comment: I have a problem with the word "now" mixed with the "had gone."  Can someone tell me why that is OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"He had gone eighty-four days now without taking a fish." I see your "problem", as you call it.

This sentence uses an expression, "to go without", which means "to be denied or deprived of (something, esp food)".

Further, when we refer to the quantity of time that has gone by, we use the word, "now", which means, "it's been eighty-four days *until* now".

"He didn't take a fish during eighty-four days." - There *is* a problem with this sentence. It's not conveying the same meaning as the original sentence, with respect to the use of *tense*. "He had not eaten (caught) a fish for eighty-four days." is close. "for" conveys the same meaning as "during" in such contexts.

Comment: @ab2 nice question, According to that answer, I guess "had not cought" is not right meaning, I mean if I use that second sentence it means "to eat" wrongly, so thats why I need to use "had not eaten" not "to cought".

Comment: Peter Schor says this is  a quote from Hemingway. Thus, "take" in this context in all probability means "catch" not "eat".  "had not caught a fish" would be OK.  But you are correct that "had not taken" can, in some contexts, mean "had not eaten."  (This is merely my first comment, modified to be more informative.)

Comment: @ab2 nice question, According to that answer, I guess "had not cought" is not right meaning, I mean if I use that second sentence it means "to eat" wrongly, so thats why I need to use "had not eaten" not "to cought". So if I use cought here, I could use: Today is very nice day He was in the sea during eighty-four days and until now He had not caouht a fish"

Comment: My pleasure! Edited as per comments, and based on the likely context.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. I read it as "(at the past instant that we are imagining) he had gone eighty-four days now (emphasing that we are to imagine that particular instant)" without taking a fish. The effect of the sentence is to place the reader firmly with the man at that moment in the past. Your alternative is a correct construction but gives no such feeling, merely a statement that someone sometime hadn't caught fish for 84 days.

Answer (score 1):

> **He had gone eighty-four days now without taking a fish.**
>
> If i was the writer of that sentence, I think I would use something
>   like:
>
> *He didn't take a fish during eighty-four days.*

Well, Michael, that's why he's Hemingway and you're not :)

*During* and *for* express different ideas with respect to time.

"During" refers to time as a bounded duration.

**I do not see her *during* the work-week, only on weekends, because she lives in Washington D.C. and I live in Philadelphia.**

But the Hemingway passage requires a word that refers to the time-span as a *measure* (length) of time.  To refer to a *length* of time we use "for":

**I have not seen my uncle for five years.**

**I have not seen my uncle during five years.**  [ungrammatical]